# Is there a way to automate the tests results in Squash TM?

Tags: jenkins, squash

I would like to know if it is possible to import tests results from Jenkins to Squash TM ? Or is there any way to import tests results to Squash after an automated test ? (to do that, TestLink for example has a special attribute class to deal with automated test)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your automated tests are written using [Squash TA](http://www.squashtest.org/en/decouvrir-squash-ta/contenu-statique/outils-et-fonctionnalites/squash-ta-test-automation-en), you can [integrate Squash TM with Jenkins](https://sites.google.com/a/henix.fr/wiki-squash-ta/tm---ta-guide/1---principle) so that Squash TM triggers automated tests and tests results are posted back to Squash TM.

Otherwise, it's not possible up to the upcoming 1.14 version. I'm not yet aware of the roadmap for later versions.